# Sum of arctan series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Would you please tell me how to calculate the following sum:

$$\sum_{k \to \infty} \arctan \frac{10^k}{10^{2k} +1}$$

The sum above is found in following [link](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/ratio-of-two-real-numbers.10886/#post-96368) containing a solution for the problem:

> Let a and b are two real numbers. What is the probability that leading digit of a/b is 1. Leading digit in 0.001980 is 1.

I tried hard to figure out but no luck.

Comment: i have only a numerical value

Comment: Can you differentiate term by term? Then integrate the result of the sum?

Comment: WolframAlpha say [the answer is 0.109798](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k+to+infinity+(arctan((10%5Ek)%2F(10%5E(2k)%2B1)))&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22to%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22LimitWord%22%7D)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a closed form and doubt one exists. If all you want is a numerical value, then by (the right half of) the well-known inequality $$\sin x < x < \tan x$$ we have $\arctan x < x$, so $$\arctan \frac{10^k}{10^{2k}+1} < \frac{10^k}{10^{2k}+1} <\frac{10^k}{10^{2k}} = 10^{-k}.$$

Moreover, for very small $x$ this is a good approximation as well. (It's the first term of the Taylor series.) So if we compute the first $k$ terms, the remaining terms are bounded by $10^{-k} + 10^{-k-1} + 10^{-k-2} + \dotsb$ which is $\frac{10}{9} \cdot 10^{-k}$.

Just taking $\arctan \frac12 + \frac19 \approx 0.575$ is a pretty good approximation. If we extend this to $\arctan \frac12 + \arctan \frac{10}{101} + \frac1{90} \approx 0.573447$, we turn out to have the first $5$ digits correct, and we can keep getting better and better approximations by going to $$\arctan \frac12 + \arctan \frac{10}{101} + \arctan \frac{100}{10001} + \frac{1}{900}$$ and beyond.

Comment: Thank you so much! If there's no closed form for the sum, the best approach to approximate is via using programming :D